# Limit a variable in pascal from one to ten

Tags: freepascal

```
program Project1;
uses
  math;
var
  num1: integer;
  power: integer;
  answer: integer;
begin
  writeln('This program will accept two input values and raise the first number to the power of the second value');
  writeln('Please enter the first number');
  readln(num1);
  writeln('Please enter the second number');
  readln(power);

  answer:= (num1**power);
  writeln(answer);
  readln();
end.
```

I have been researching hours tirelessly to find how you limit variables from 1-10 please could anyone tell me how you limit variable num1 from 1 to ten

Comment: Subrange variables should do the job:
`var num1: 1 .. 100;`
This of course will not help you validating the user input and might lead to unexpected behaviour if the user enters an invalid value. You should take the user input as is and check in your code if it is valid...

Comment: You need to write bespoke code to check validity of input. Do that in a loop, using if statements to check validity, and only exiting the loop when the input is valid. Subrange types are of no use here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To validate an input, one possibility is to make a function that validates it for you.
Pass the value and min, max ranges and set the function value according to the test result.

```
function ValidInteger( value : Integer; min,max : Integer) : Boolean;
begin
  Result := (value >= min) and (value <= max); // Or ValidInteger := etc
end;
```

In your code that would look like:

```
min := 1;
max := 10;
repeat
  writeln('Please enter the first number [',min,'..',max,']:');
  readln(num1);
until ValidInteger(num1,min,max);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help